# Flutter: Vertical scrolling inside a container

Tags: flutter

How do I add scrolling so that the multiple Text answers are scrollable? I have tried working with SingleChildScrollView but can't get the scrolling to work, the Text answers disappear and the page doesn't scroll.

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        color: Color(0xfff4f4f4),
        textColor: Color(0xff3a3535),
        child: Text(answerText, style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'VT323', fontSize: 22)),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 238),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(offset: Offset(10, 10),color: Color.fromARGB(80, 0, 0, 0),blurRadius: 10),
          BoxShadow(offset: Offset(-10, -10),color: Color.fromARGB(150, 255, 255, 255),blurRadius: 10)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ListView.builder 
Here I get the following error:

"type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List'

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final List<String> answerText;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 60.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 238),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(10, 10),
                color: Color.fromARGB(80, 0, 0, 0),
                blurRadius: 10),
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(-10, -10),
              color: Color.fromARGB(150, 255, 255, 255),
              blurRadius: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: _buildAnswerItem,
          itemCount: answerText.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildAnswerItem( BuildContext context, int index) {
    return RaisedButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 16.0),
      color: Color(0xfff4f4f4),
      textColor: Color(0xff3a3535),
      child: Text(answerText[index],
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'VT323', fontSize: 22)),
      onPressed: selectHandler,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try using ListView

Comment: @AnuroopSingh Can you show me how I would do this? I have tried ListView as well  but as I am new to Flutter,  I couldn't quite get it to work.

Comment: Have you checked the docs? [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to enable scrolling by just adding SingleChildScrollView at another level:

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff4f4f4),
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        title: Text('...', style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'VT323',
            fontSize: 30,
            color: Color(0xffff7315)),),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
```

rather than trying to add the SingleChildScrollView here:

```
return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        color: Color(0xfff4f4f4),
        textColor: Color(0xff3a3535),
```

And this has worked wonderfully in two different parts of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ListView:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 238, 238),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
          offset: Offset(10, 10),
          color: Color.fromARGB(80, 0, 0, 0),
          blurRadius: 10),
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(-10, -10),
        color: Color.fromARGB(150, 255, 255, 255),
        blurRadius: 10,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        color: Color(0xfff4f4f4),
        textColor: Color(0xff3a3535),
        child: Text(answerText,
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'VT323', fontSize: 22)),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Code with a ListView.builder:

```
List<String> answers = [
"Answer1",
"Answer2",
"Answer3",
"Answer4",
"Answer5",
"Answer6",
"Answer7"
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    height: 60,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
    width: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.green,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: answers.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            color: Color(0xfff4f4f4),
            textColor: Color(0xff3a3535),
            child: Text(
              answers[index],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'VT323',
                fontSize: 22,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Answer $index tapped");
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still getting the error on questions where there are longer list items though so I would need it to scroll. How would I do this?

Comment: @SKdev I couldn't understand your problem, Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Basically I need the list of Text answers to scroll.  The number of answers to each question vary through the quiz and when there are 5 or more possible answers an error appears as there is no scrolling.

Comment: @SKdev I thinks you should use a ListView.builder instead of a simple ListView and pass your answers List.

Comment: That's what I'm trying at the moment, but i'm getting an error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type of type List<String>.

Comment: Chances are you are passing a List od strings instead of a single string. Can you update you code in the question ?

Comment: I have just updated my question with the code for the  ListView.builder.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I try this I get continuous errors. Isn't there a simpler way to just add scrolling to my original code by adding ScrollView rather than having to add ListView.builder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211468/discussion-between-abdelbaki-boukerche-and-skdev).